# Never bind domain objects to your view - True or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Online I saw someone say "When working with a view, create a view model. This view model you will bind to your view. Never bind domain objects to your view."

Is this good practice, to "never bind domain objects to your view"? What's the thinking behind this?

Thanks!

Comment: See [this post and all the answers/discussions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/821276/304683).

Answer (score 1):

we use view model when our domain object is different from view e.g

i have two models

```
Student

Subjects
```

and i want a single view to display table of `Students` and table of `Subjects` so what will i do ? i will use view model like

```
class viewmodeltest
 {
   public list<Student> students {get;set;}
   public list<Subjects> subjects {get;set;}

 }
```

and yes its best practice to use view model because all UI validation logic is done on the view models with `data annotations`